# How do I get to the form in visual c# express

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-express

whenever I click on the form in the project view I get the code, I want to open up the form in design view.  I know it's there because when I run it the form come up.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can press SHIFT + F7 (or right-click and select View Designer) to open the form designer when you have the file highlighted.

[image]

Comment: got it, I was in class view I had to go to solution explorer

Answer (score 1):

You need to right click on it and select "View Designer", at least that's what I do in VS2010, unless it's changed.  Let me know if that helps?